# SpriteKit full screen texture reducing framerate

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am currently developping a game with SpriteKit and I have a performance issue.
I noticed that with 15 or more SpriteNodes animated on scene, my code is running without any problem at 60 fps.
But as soon as I add a full screen SpriteNode to the scene, for exemple a background texture, the framerate fall around 30 fps, even if it's just a red rectangle.

I assume there is something that I don't understand about rendering.
What's happening ? How one texture can divide by 2 the performance ? Is someone got the same issue ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That should not happen. Post some relevant code for your nodes, especially your background node.

Comment: You are seeing the fps drop on a device? Which one? If you're testing Simulator, ignore it, it's not representative of device performance in the least bit.

Comment: Yep thank you, I was testing on the simulator. I will not worry about it anymore if it doesn't happen on a real device.  @sangony: there is nothing special in the code. It happens just by creating a node with + (instancetype)spriteNodeWithColor:(SKColor *)color size:(CGSize)size and adding it to the scene when the size of the scene and the size of the SpriteNode is full screen.